# Flutter Audiocache - Change volume while playing

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if it's possible to change volume of Audiocache player in flutter **on the go** - without restarting current song.

In documentation volume is mentioned twice. You can set it when you call **play** or **loop**. None of that will work for me.

> Also maybe I took the wrong path and there is a less painful way to play music with Flutter?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got it.

To be able to change volume we need to initiate instance of AudioPlayer that serves as kind of controller for AudioCache.

```dart
  static AudioPlayer advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  static AudioCache player = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);
```

Then we can set volume by simply doing:

```dart
  void changeVolume(double value) {
    advancedPlayer.setVolume(value);
  }
```

Comment: Well I can't get this either to work. At least not in my XCode simulator setup.

Answer (score 0):

try This inside initState..I know it deosn't make sense but it worked for me lol .

```
audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = event == PlayerState.PLAYING;
    audioPlayer.setVolume(1.0);
  });
});
```